# An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge: Error: Could not find any Electron packages in devDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, neutronium

After using npm-start for a web-app, npm have problems with Dependencies, i can't figure out why, i try to reinstall npm, node.js ecc... but nothing

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find any Electron packages in devDependencies
at getElectronModuleName (C:\Users\Utente\yt-clone\node_modules@electron-forge\core\src\util\electron-version.ts:56:11)
at getElectronVersion (C:\Users\Utente\yt-clone\node_modules@electron-forge\core\src\util\electron-version.ts:92:23)
at _default (C:\Users\Utente\yt-clone\node_modules@electron-forge\core\src\api\start.ts:49:11)
at C:\Users\Utente\yt-clone\node_modules@electron-forge\cli\src\electron-forge-start.ts:58:19

```
Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

Comment: What "web-app" are you using? Is it a template from github? Some sort of CLI generator? Have you tried running `npm i` before doing `npm start`?

Comment: yep sorry for the late response, it was a problem of my machine, i used linux instead and it worked for me, thanks anyway